# Is it typical to use protectowrap on a deck ledger?

Tags: deck

My deck has protectowrap between some of the house and deck boards. I never noticed this anywhere else before. Is this typical? I either need to replace it or remove it and paint instead. I’m inclined to paint but I would like some advice as far as how to proceed. I’m in the process of removing the boards to gain necessary access now.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Here’s the deck after boards removed

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that was installed for a reason. A common rot location has been behind ledger boards such as this. Even with metal cap flashing water tends to run behind, and it doesn't dry out well. This results in rot of the sheathing and joists behind.

Normally the siding is close enough to the deck that you don't see the flashing. You might overlay something to conceal the membrane. To avoid fastener holes it could be adhered with silicone or urethane caulk and held in place with the decking.